# Start up ganache-cli ethereum client in travis CI for testing

Tags: truffle, json-rpc

I'm trying to write a .travis.yml file to test my ethereum contract.

In order to test it, I need to start up an instance of the ganache-cli ethereum client by calling

```
ganache-cli -p 7545
```

and then run some truffle commands:

```
truffle compile
truffle migrate
```

However, if I put the ganache-cli command in the script section of my .travis.yml file like so:

```
script:
- ganache-cli -p 7545
- truffle migrate 
- truffle test
```

My truffle commands are never called because the entire terminal instance is taken over by the instance of the ganache-cli client that is started up.

I've tried putting the ganache-cli call in before-scripts like so:

```
before-script:
- ganache-cli -p 7545
script:
- truffle compile
- truffle migrate --network development
- truffle test
```

Using the above code, the ethereum client is never started. Does anyone have any idea how to setup my .travis.yml file to both start the ganache-cli client as well as allow me to call my truffle migrate/test commands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following script:

```
script:
- ganache-cli -p 7545 > /dev/null &
- sleep 5
- truffle migrate 
- truffle test
```

Comment: First script didn't work, second one worked though! Thanks.

Comment: I'll update the answer, and remove first one.